# How to merge two prototypes in Pencil Wireframing Tool?

Tags: merge, prototype

I am using Pencil wire framing tool. I have distributed the modules with my developers and now I want to merge all of them in a single solution. Instead of copy pasting page by page I think there can be a better way of doing this.
Also I wanted to know, is it possible of converting the one source file of prototype into another as I think collaboration feature in Pencil is missing.
Please assist.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Open `.ep` files in your favorite editor. You will see an XML structure like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Document xmlns="http://www.evolus.vn/Namespace/Pencil">
 <Properties/>
  <Pages>
   <page>...</page>
   <page>...</page>
   .....
   .....
  </Pages>
</Document>
```

Now just copy paste second `.ep` files all `<page>` at end of first `.ep` (Just before `</pages>`